# How do I select a file and paste the file path in an embdedded text box?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to allow a user to select a file and then have that path placed in an embedded textbox so the file name can be used for future reference.

```
Sub Select_File()

    Dim FilePath As FileDialog
    Set FilePath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    FilePath.AllowMultiSelect = False

    With FilePath
       If .Show = -1 Then
        SMPS_Path.Text = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
       Else
         MsgBox "You have cancelled the action"
        [SMPS_Path] = ""
        End If
       End With
End Sub
```

The embedded textbox I created is named `SMPS_Path` and I am trying to get the File path to paste here but I keep erroring out at `SMPS_Path.Text = .SelectedItems.Item(1)`

What can I do to have the file path  that is selected in the `File` Dialog to be placed in the textbox?

Eventually I'll use the Import button to open that file and import the data I want into this spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: "keep erroring out " doesn't tell us much  - what is the error message ?

Comment: The error says Run-time error '404' Object Required

Comment: Likely your code is not able to resolve `SMPS_Path` into an object.  You don't give much info about where the textbox is, and it would also help to mention which program you're working in (Excel?  Access?)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting here.  I included a screen shot of where the textbox is relative to the Command button. This is in Excel.

Comment: SMPS_Path is that the text box name?

Comment: On a worksheet?  In a useform?  Where is your code located?

Comment: Yes, I named the textbox SMPS_Path.

Comment: My Code is located in the Cmd button "Select File" (image above). I named the Macro cmd button Select_File and this is located in a Module...

Comment: `SMPS_Path.Text` will throw an error unless SMPS_Path has focus. Try `SMPS_Path = .SelectedItems.Item(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

*Should be*

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox1 = .SelectedItems(1)
```

a*ssuming your textbox is on sheet1*

Comment: @SamiiiWarr Cool Feel free to mark answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-) see link here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619